# How can I use the same shell I worked in the past as I was disconnect by long time no operation in Putty?

Tags: linux, shell, rhel, gnu-screen, putty

Last night I was debugging with GDB. The GDB is a remote Red hat machine, and I log into with putty. I didn't finish my debug last night, and I left.

But this morning when I come back ,the PuTTy is disconnect with the Ret Hat Shell, and I login the Red hat machine, find that the GDB is still runnning, but I am not in the same shell as the one in last night. How can I still use that GDB instance to keep my debugging. I don't won't to restart the whole program since it takes much time to build and run.

Comment: You tagged gnu-screen, which along with tmux, would have saved you, if you started your original session with them.

Answer (score 1):

Use a multiplexer like [tmux](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/tmux/) or [screen](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Screen/) on the remote site.

In the case you use tmux:

When logged in on the remote site with putty simply start the multiplexer by executing `tmux`. Disconnect from tmux multiplexer by pressing `CTRL-b d`, than disconnect putty. When returning to the remote site list your tmux session with `tmux ls` and reconnect with `tmux attach`.

There are a lot of features to secure your session so read the contents of the links above.

I don't know a way to reconnect to your already started debugging session, so this is an advice for next time also.

Comment: If this is what you were looking for it would be nice, if you accept my answer. ;)

Comment: I'll give an upvote, and pend it for an answer for some days. :)

Answer (score 0):

(advice for next time) Try using nohup

https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm

You can also set the heartbeat / keepalive on putty to a greater number than 0:

https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/keep-putty-ssh-sessions-from-disconnecting/

Comment: `nohup` won't help if the network layer connecting to the shell session has closed